# S Health Developer Mode Pixel 2 5.14.0003

Tags: android

So I followed the instructions for enabling developer mode on my pixel 2.  Go into the about, tap the version 10+ times, seems very simple.  Doesn't work.  Is there another requirement i.e Pixel can't do it?  Did it recently change?  I can activate "Send Log Files" if I tap the Samsung Health logo 10 times, but no developer mode.  Phone (the pixel, not the app) is already in developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

So after tapping on this screen for 2 hours, I cleared the cache (twice) after a force stop.  I very carefully tapped 10 times on the version (5.14.0003) and the thing turned on.  I'm never turning it off.